# python kivy multiple labels

Tags: python, label, kivy

I'm trying to make more labels in a for loop but I'm always getting an wierd problem. Even though the program goes through whole for loop it doesn't make all labels.
Here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def draw(self):
        with self.canvas:           

            for i in range(6):
                print('I draw label')
                Label(text = 'hello', pos=(i*100, 100))
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = MyWidget()
        game.draw()
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or how would you solve the problem please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, a few things are wrong here.

canvas is for gl instructions, it's literally where you "paint" your widget, not whole widgets (like Label is).

When you create a widget, if you want it to be visible, you have to add it to a parent widget (itself visible, because added to a visible parent), here i understand the intent is for these Labels to be children of your `game` widget, so change MyWidget.draw to something like:

```
    def draw(self):
        for i in range(6):
            print('I draw label')
            self.add_widget(Label(text='hello', pos=(i*100, 100))
```

should do what you want.